# Celery does not registering tasks

Tags: python, django, celery

Hello! I just started to use Celery with Django. I've a task that i need to be periodic. In admin interface I can see my task in dropdown list named "Task (registered):". But when Celery Beat tries to execute it NotRegistered exception is thrown.

Python 3.5.2, Django 1.11.4, Celery 4.1, django-celery-beat 1.1.0, django-celery-results 1.0.1

Part of settings.py related to celery:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://user:*****@192.168.X.X/proj'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'django-db'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Europe/Moscow'
```

celery.py and proj/__init__.py are identical to documentation examples.

proj/celery.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'proj.settings')

app = Celery('proj')

app.config_from_object(settings, namespace='CELERY')

app.autodiscover_tasks()

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

proj/__init__.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ['celery_app']
```

tasks.py:

```
from celery import shared_task
from core.backend.files import SFTP

@shared_task
def load_files_from_sftp():
    ftp = SFTP()
    ftp.get_files()
```

I get the following json result: 
{"exc_message": "'core.tasks.load_files_from_sftp'", "exc_type": "NotRegistered"}

If I try to use celery.task.control.inspect() from shell, it is only debug_task() there. Just stuck! ( I'll be grateful for any help.

Comment: `from django.apps import apps`

```app.config_from_object(settings)```

`app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: [n.name for n in apps.get_app_configs()])`

Comment: @MuhammadShoaib Bless You! Thats it! Thank you! Why official docs doesnt have it?

Comment: Yeah, not sure, we also have that in our project, instead of Autodiscover, we are manually passing the apps to autodiscovery function. Glad it worked for you.

Comment: @MuhammadShoaib Yes, now the tasks are registered, but the periodic tasks are not started on time. Just few times a day, while period is every minute ((( Oh, but thats another story...

Comment: Fun fact: if your tasks.py has any import errors in it, celery will fail to register the whole file and will never tell you about it. They try to import tasks.py and if there is any import error, they assume the whole file does not exist and carry on. It's actually a common design mistake in python projects.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As @MuhammadShoaib wrote, it's just one thing:

```
from django.apps import apps 

app.config_from_object(settings)
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: [n.name for n in apps.get_app_configs()])
```

instead of

```
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

why this is not in the documentation?...

Comment: where do I get the variable settings from? the default version is app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

Comment: I think this was a bug. I know that Celery 4.3 does not require this anymore and I think it was fixed earlier than that.

Comment: Don't forget to put your app (AppConfig) in INSTALLED_APPS to be auto-discovered.

Comment: `app.autodiscover_tasks(['some_folder'])` can be useful in case of non-app directories.

Answer (score 8):

This might hopefully help someone. 
I modified my code and neglected to restart the celery worker.
`Restarting the celery workers` helped.

Comment: Yes this helped me.. you saved my time :)

Comment: Thank you for this. My problem was a bit different, but your answer helped me sort it out. I am manually testing locally as well as running a suite of automated tests with PyTest. I had my worker running, and this caused conflicts with my tests. Once I stopped the worker, my tests passed. Thanks!

Comment: glad to hear! you should probably consider isolating the test environment if you can so it's reproducible.