# celery 4.3.0 : get variable from inside current task

Tags: django, python-3.x, celery

I have this task which is designed to bulk insert or delete objects in database :

**views.py**

```
from .tasks import run_task_with
def index():
    # some code to retrieve obj_list
    run_task_with(insert_obj, obj_list).delay()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/app_root/')
```

**tasks.py**

```
@shared_task
def run_task_with(func, queryset):
    cache.add('current_task_id', run_task_with.request.id)
    obj_numb = len(queryset)
    r = map(func, queryset)
    for i, obj in enumerate(r):
        sleep(0.1)
        progress_percent = int(round(float(i) / float(obj_numb) * 100))
        current_task.update_state(
            state='PROGRESS',
            meta={'progress_percent': progress_percent}
        )
```

But *run_task_with.request.id* keeps returning None even while object insertions runs smoothly. Could anyone explain to me why ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer found here : [Celery does not registering tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47630459/celery-does-not-registering-tasks)

```
from django.apps import apps 
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: [n.name for n in apps.get_app_configs()])
```

And for subsidiary issue (to be able to pass function *func* to task) :

```
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json', 'pickle']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'pickle'
```